# Magento Admin credentials invalid error

Tags: magento, admin

I am entering the right credentials in admin section of the magento website, but still getting the **Invalid Username/Passwrod**

I logged into the cPanel, went into phpMyAdmin and changed the password(MD5) in database itself, but still getting the same error.

Does the following line has anything to do with it

`php_value memory_limit 128M`

I had to delete this from my **.htaccess** file after migrating to new host, since it was producing 500 error and the new host asked me so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change you password by running the following Query:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

`qX` is the salt so you can change it to whatever you want just make sure to change it in both place in the query, and `'admin'` is obviously the user name so change that to whichever username is yours.

Comment: I edited it the normal way by entering into the table. And then editing it. What's the difference?

Comment: You must update with salt otherwise it wont work properly. Did you try my suggestion above?

Comment: Ohh k. I will do this now. Give me a minute. Will reply after check

Comment: Whis is this happening. BTW, I also changed the password for other user and was able to login with it. But, it didn't had full permission and can only add products. May be it isn't assigned the full administrative roles.

Comment: I created a new admin user. Then inserted a new record to the admin_role table and entered **parent_id=1 tree_level=2 sort_order=0 and role_type=U** . Are these values correct??. I am able to login and see the complete menu now. But, when i click on some links, i see error `Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually` .